# Simple Quartus compiling error related to device restrictions

Tags: synthesis, intel-fpga, quartus

I have a relatively simple circuit that I'm trying to compile. It requires 491 I/O pins, so I'm selecting a non-default device that has more than 456 (Cyclone IV GX with 508 user I/Os). The problem is that when compiling I receive this error:

> Error: Can't place 489 pins with 1.2 V I/O standard because Fitter has
>   only 380 such free pins available for general purpose I/O placement

I'm not sure what this 380 free pins mean, I'm sure that the I/O pins should be enough, I can see it in the report:

> ```
> Total Pins 491 / 508 ( 97 % )
> ```

I think that is probably because it's talking about some other type of pin I'm not aware of (I'm just starting with electronics and VHDL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all pins on a given FPGA can support every I/O standard.  That error message indicates that there are only 380 pins that support 1.2V I/O pins.  You will need to assign some of your pins to a standard that is compatible with the other pins.  The device documentation or Quartus should have documentation on which pins support what I/O standards.

Comment: Thanks!! I do not mind changing the device to one that has 500 1.2V I/O pins, is there any way I could find such device?

Comment: I would suspect there is a device that would satisfy your requirements but I can't recommend one.  Look at Altera's parts and see what they offer.  Xilinx is the other big name in FPGAs so you could look at their products as well.

Comment: Thank you *very* much again. I found one in the ArriaGX family!